# How do I pass data values to a form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have an application I am working on for a fantasy football site. If you go here:

http://digitaldemo.net/kickass/a-results.php

You can see what the admin will see when they go to view / edit players.

UPDATE--------------------------------------

This is the relevant code on a-results.php that renders the data and *should* pass data on to the form on qb-edit.php:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1" width="560">
<tr style="text-align:center">
<td style="text-align:left ; width:175px">Player Name</td>
<td>Team</td>
<td>Pass Yds</td>
<td>Pass TDs</td>
<td>Int Thrown</td>
<td>Rush Yds</td>
<td>Rush TDs</td>
<td>Overall Pts</td>
<td>TFP</td>
</tr>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Overall_Pts, Total_Fantasy_Pts FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'QB' ORDER BY Pass_Yds DESC;");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr style=\"text-align:center\"><td style=\"text-align:left\">{$row['Player']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Team']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Pass_Yds']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Pass_TDs']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Int_Thrown']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Rush_Yds']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Rush_TDs']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Overall_Pts']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Total_Fantasy_Pts']}</td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"qb-edit.php\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ID\" value=\"". $row['ID'] ."\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\"></form></td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

and this is the contents of qb-edit.php:

```
<?php
$posted_id = $_POST['ID'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body    { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
font-size:14px ;
}

.form   { width:350px ;
margin-auto ;
}

label   { clear:both ;
display:block ;
float:left ;
padding-right:8px ;
line-height:26px ;
}

input[type=text]    { float:right ;
width:163px ;
height:18px ;
margin:3px 0px ;
} 

input[type=text].short  { width:30px ;
margin-right:132px ;
}

input[type=submit]  { clear:both ;
float:left ;
margin-top:20px ;
margin-bottom:20px ;
}

select  { float:right ;
margin-right:118px ;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="form">            
<?php 

echo $posted_id;

$result = mysql_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM ff_projections where ID='" . $posted_id . "'") or die ("Error in query");
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<form method='post' action='add_player.php'>";
echo "<label for='Player'>Player Name:</label> <input type='text' name='Player' value='" . $row['Player'] . "' />";
echo "<label for='Pass_Yds'>Pass Yds:</label> <input class='short' type='text' name='Pass_Yds' value='" . $row['Pass_Yds'] . "' />";
echo "<label for='Pass_TDs'>Pass TDs:</label> <input class='short' type='text' name='Pass_TDs' value='" . $row['Pass_TDs'] . "' />";
echo "<label for='Int_Thrown'>Int Thrown:</label> <input class='short' type='text' name='Int_Thrown' value='" . $row['Int_Thrown'] . "' />";
echo "<label for='Rush_Yds'>Rush Yds:</label> <input class='short' type='text' name='Rush_Yds' value='" . $row['Rush_Yds'] . "' />";
echo "<label for='Rush_TDs'>Rush TDs:</label> <input class='short' type='text' name='Rush_TDs' value='" . $row['Rush_TDs'] . "' />";
echo "<label for='Overall_Pts'>Overall Pts:</label> <input class='short' type='text' name='Overall_Pts' value='" . $row['Overall_Pts'] . "' />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update Player' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['ID'] . "' />";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I get an error that says:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\kickass\\qb-edit.php on line 55, referer: http://localhost/kickass/a-results.php
```

This is line 55 of qb-edit.php:

```
$result = mysql_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM ff_projections where ID='" . $posted_id . "'") or die ("Error in query");
```

I'm going nuts trying to get this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the ID for their database record as a parameter, probably as a hidden field, and then use it to pull their record from the database on the next page.

Comment: In each of those forms that comprise those buttons put the ID number of the record associated with each player. You can then get that ID as a `$_POST` variable on the qb-edit.php page and use it to get their information from your database.

Comment: So would the Edit button form code look like this then: <form action="qb-edit.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ID" value="$ID"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"></form>?

Answer (score 1):

the idea is that you pass the ID of the player (could be as GET or as a POST method), I think that the best way is the POST because you can pass the ID into the URL

for example:

**player_id = 1 Vince Young** if you create a link to this page http://digitaldemo.net/kickass/edit_player.php?id=1 it will display the edit page

**player_id = 2 Ryan Tannehill** if you create a link to this page http://digitaldemo.net/kickass/edit_player.php?id=2 it will display the edit page

etc etc

of course you have to considerate some stuff:

1. You have to create a php file called edit_player and the functions on it.
2. You have to validate the SESSION['user'] has the permission to edit a player, if you don't check that someone can open a browser copy and paste a link like this :http://digitaldemo.net/kickass/edit_player.php?id=1 and will able to edit your post.
3. If I'll use some kind of md5 algorithm to send the user ID, doing that I will restrict the intruder.

please take a look to this security guide, it will help you to protect your site:

http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/

Answer (score 1):

your errors are caused here I do believe

"SELECT * FROM ff_projections where ID='" . $posted_id . "'"

you started your double quotes before SELECT  which is good
however when you got to ID=  you ended that set of quotes
Remove the double quotes

so in other words

```
"SELECT * FROM ff_projections WHERE ID = '$posted_id'"
```

instead of

```
 "SELECT * FROM ff_projections where ID='" . $posted_id . "'"
```

Comment: Sigh...stupid mistake on my part. I never connected qb-edit.php to the stupd db. ARGH! Must. get. sleeeep... Thank you for the help!